# Does Docker support filesystems written in FUSE mounted on host OS？

Tags: docker, kubernetes, filesystems, fuse

if a filesystem writted in FUSE mounted on host, can containers started by Docker use it? I use k8s to deploy containers and want to do something by FUSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [host path volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) is [bind mounted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/198590/22470) into a container. So anything available on the host will become available in the container.

A FUSE volume is not directly supported by kubernetes, as in provisioning a PVC on a node via some fuse driver but `hostPath` should work fine.